# Multi begin Sql, proteção de dados do banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, transações

Em minha aplicação faço o uso de `BEGIN;`, `COMMIT;`, `ROLLBACK;`, `Try`, `Catch`:

#### Exemplo:

```
try{
    $this->execute('BEGIN;');
        // CODIGO COM VALIDAÇÕES
    $this->execute('COMMIT;');
}catch(Exception $e){
    $this->execute('ROLLBACK;');
}
```

Acontece que para fins de teste eu seto uma flag que ativa o `BEGIN;`, `ROLLBACK;` Global

#### Exemplo

```
function __construct(){
    if($this->transaction_rollback === true){
        $this->Execute('BEGIN;');
    }
}

function __destruct(){
    if($this->transaction_rollback === true){
        $this->Execute('ROLLBACK;');
    }
}
```

#### Resumo

```
BEGIN;
    BEGIN;    //there is already a transaction in progress
        // INSERT 
    COMMIT;
ROLLBACK;     //there is no transaction in progress
```

#### Situação

Eu utilizo `postgreSql` e pelos testes ele não tem suporte a multi `BEGIN;`,
pesquisando um pouso também não encontrei outros bancos que teriam suporte a esta situação.

#### Questão

Teria alguma outra maneira de proteger o banco para fins de testes?

Comment: Você por acaso não está fazendo confusão de "multiplos begin" com savepoint ? -> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-savepoint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solução

Criei métodos que executarão o `BEGIN;`, `COMMIT;`, `ROLLBACK;`

#### Exemplo

```
function begin(){
    $this->Execute('BEGIN;');
}

function commit(){
    $this->Execute('COMMIT;');
}

function rollback(){
    $this->Execute('ROLLBACK;');
}
```

contudo no `commit` fiz a alteração para contemplar a flag `transaction_rollback`, ficando

```
function commit(){
    if($this->transaction_rollback === true){ 
        $this->rollback(); 
        return;
    }
    $this->Execute('COMMIT;');
}
```

#### Resumo

```
BEGIN;
    // INSERT 
ROLLBACK;
```